# How do I integrate an iOS Codename One app with a Beta Testing platform like TestFairy?

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm currently developing an app using Codename One, but I need to send an in-development build to the client for viewing, but they don't have a jailbroken device that they can test the debug build on, so I've opted to use a service like www.testfairy.com - problem is they require for you to implement some code into base functions (for example, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)

Is there a way I can integrate with one of these services?

Comment: Why can't you implement the code in those methods?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't have access to them as Codename One is scripted using Java - it could be exposed for editing, but I'm not sure where to go with it.

Comment: You said the problem is you need to put code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. What's wrong with that?

Comment: As far as I was aware all of the base 'Objective C' functions were essentially hidden with the Java Codename Name framework at viewing level (Codename One provides multi-platform building, so having the iOS functions and calls there wouldn't make much sense for the Android builds) - but as the comment from Shai has informed me I can send arguments to the build server (http://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_sending_arguments_to_the_build_server), so it looks like I might be able to inject code there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has TestFlight which is their official beta testing solution, Codename One has full TestFlight integration detailed here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/location-ios-beta-testing-better-input.html

Comment: Is this feature avaliable to the Basic subscription?

Comment: Notice that you can add code to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions see http://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_sending_arguments_to_the_build_server `ios.beforeFinishLaunching`

Comment: Thanks for both of those points, I'll have to see if I can do something with the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for now, as I can't afford Pro at this time.

Comment: @Shai Almog: can you give an example of how you would link a procedure with the `ios.beforeFinishLaunching` build hint? How do you link it to native interface code for iOS? Thanks.

Comment: You can inject code into the native method. I don't have the code you might want to inject